# Search block not showing if not logged in

Tags: search, configuration

When I am logged in I can see the the search form block, however when logged out I can not see it, I'm guessing its some sort of user config, but I can't seem to find anything

Answer (score 2):

> You have to go to the `Administer › User management` section, under the search module area, you need to give the necessary permission to the user that needs to see the search form. If you want everyone to view this `Search Module` check the box corresponding to `anonymous` and `authenticated` users.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027332/1795426